# Spring deferredresult with ajax request

Tags: spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I am using spring deferredresult(servlet 3 async) for an ajax request processing.But after the deferedresult is returned , I am not getting the response object, in the ajax request success method.Anyone have any idea what can be the reason for this?am i missing something in the configuration?

Following is the ajax call code :

```
function sendajaxreq() {
    $
            .ajax({
                url : "plantView/testLink",
                type : "GET",
                data : "",
                cache : false,
                success : function(messages) {
                    alert(messages);
                },
                error : function(xhr) {
                    if (xhr.statusText != "abort" && xhr.status != 503) {
                        console
                                .error("Unable to retrieve chat messages. Chat ended.");
                    }
                }
            })
}
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testLink", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<Map<String, WebView>> testLink() {

    DeferredResult<Map<String, WebView>> chartsResult = new       DeferredResult<Map<String, WebView>>();

    Map<String, WebView> res = processSampleReq();
    chartsResult.setResult(res);
     chartsResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     System.out.println("deffered res completed");
     }
     });

    return chartsResult;
}
```

Even after returning the chartsResult I am getting the messages as null in the ajaxcall success method.

In web.xml the only change i have made for deffered result to work is that added async-support for the dispatcher servlet and filer mappings.

I am using Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE version and Tomcat 7.0.34.

Thanks,
Dipti.

Comment: where is the client code, the controller code, web.xml/configuration class?

Comment: Pls see this [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10410) created on Spring (that was resolved as Invalid) !
They faced the exact same issue you faced !
The only way is to set the deferredResult outside of the Controller service method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue.Actually I have a filter which post process the response to gzip it and that was the reason for the issue.when this filter was removed,the defferedresult worked.

Thanks, Dipti.

Answer (score 1):

DeferredResult is meant to be returned by the Controller **without** calling `setResult()` in the same thread. `setResult()` has to be called by another thread. See [Introducing Servlet 3 Async Support](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/) (SpringSource team blog). But this has IMO nothing to do with your empty message.

If you want to produce [JSON with @ResponseBody](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) you have to make sure that spring finds Jackson in the classpath:

> Underneath the covers, Spring MVC delegates to a HttpMessageConverter to perform the serialization. In this case, Spring MVC invokes a MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter built on the Jackson JSON processor. This implementation is **enabled automatically** when you use the mvc:annotation-driven configuration element **with Jackson present in your classpath**.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.Yeah I know the purpose of deferred result is as you meant and I want to use it like that only in my app.But with this simple case itself not working I cant get that too working wright?
Also as u mentioned i already have the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter  configured in the xml and jackson is there in my classpath and all ajax requests which don't use deferredresult works for me too.I have issue only when using deferredresult.

Comment: Hi, Any help? I am sitting behind this for more than two days :(

Comment: If one have a good tutorial or documentaion on spring 3.2 deferredresult please share.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the game but just in case anyone comes across this issue like I did... We had the same issue where the response body was disappearing and it was also due to a GZip filter. Removing this worked but simply removing it wasn't a runner for us. When creating your GZIPOutputSteam for the response the constructor will take a syncflush parameter. Setting this boolean to true allows you to keep your filter and get a populated response body.